# Многопроцессорные приложения в python: call, Popen, fork

Tags: python, процесс, multiprocessing, subprocess

Привет. Я [разбираюсь](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_Python/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) с тем, как создавать несколько процессов. В python есть несколько способов создать процесс.

- `call`
- `Popen`
- `fork`

Сильной разницы я не вижу, по крайней мере между `call` и `Popen`. Что касается, `fork`, то, видимо, он делают копию себя. А `call` и `Popen` создают новый, из другого исходного кода.

Comment: А в чем вопрос ? fork - это только под unix, call - это своего рода аналог os.system(), Popen - дает возможность выполнять команды системной оболочки (как и call) и перехватывать потоки stdin stdout stderr, ну и делать мосты между программами (процессами), если нужен мультиплатформенный вариант пользуйтесь модулем multiprocessing

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч Окей, понял. Я вот тут читаю, что многопроцессорность в питоне практически бесполезна. Поскольку GIL может дать выполнится одновременно лишь одному потоку. Я прав или нет? Т.е. фактически многопроцессорность в питоне бесполезна.

Comment: Не путайте потоки и процессы. В питоне потоки очень хорошо подходят для операций связанных с ожиданием ввода/вывода, но не подходят для вычислительных задач из-за GIL. При этом процессы могут обеспечить ускорение кода связанного с вычислениями. Для этого можете посмотреть модуль `multiprocessing` и  класс `ProcessPoolExecutor` из модуля `concurent.futures`.

Comment: GIL да есть такое дело, ну во первых есть способы его отключать, но это чревато проблемами, GIL не просто так был придуман, а вообще с ним можно жить, в больших приложениях процессы или потоки реально облегчают жизнь, даже не смотря на GIL, благодаря грамотному распределению задач между ними

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч скажем, у меня есть функция, которую нужно в разных процессах запускать. У этой функции есть аргументы. Можно ли передать ей эти аргументы как-нибудь?

Comment: @hedgehogues Process(target=func_name, args=(arg1,arg2, ...)).start(), да в параметре args передаете кортеж с аргументами если он один то args=(arg1,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subprocess.call() это по сути subprocess.Popen().wait().

Popen() это по сути os.fork() + os.execve() на Unix.

Это разные функции, которые пригодны для разных задач. В частности, они находятся на разных уровнях абстракции  (функции более низкого уровня могут быть использованы, чтобы реализовать функции более высокого уровня).